# How can I work with a Database from another app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I came to ask this question, because I don´t know not only how to do it, but I don´t know either how to search the web for some kind of clarification.

I have a web app created with MVC5, Entity Framework and Code First, where I use a grid (jsgrid).  In this app, after the user logs in, they can see the created applications and add new ones and, also, they can generate licenses (app keys) for them.

Now, the idea is to handle the license generator and Database saving (only for the licenses) from a dll module.

So, since the Database is created in the MVC application, how can I make the dll module to check into that database, to make sure the app does not have that key already, and then, save it into the database as well?

(All this code is from the MVC app)

DBContext:

```
public class LicenseDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public LicenseDataContext()
            : base("LicenseDataContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

LicenseModel

```
public class License
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ClientEmail { get; set; }
    public Status? Status { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public SendStatus? SendStatus { get; set; }
    public string SendDate { get; set; }
}

public class LicenseFilter
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ClientEmail { get; set; }
    public Status? Status { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public SendStatus? SendStatus { get; set; }
    public string SendDate { get; set; }
}
```

}

LicenseController

```
public class LicenseDataController : ApiController
{
    MailAddress addr;

    LicenseDataContext _db = new LicenseDataContext();

    LicenseDataContext DB
    {
        get { return _db; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Get()
    {
        LicenseFilter filter = GetFilter();

        var result = DB.Licenses.Where(c => c.AppName == LicenseManagerController._appName &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.AppName) || c.AppName.Contains(filter.AppName)) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.license) || c.license.Contains(filter.license)) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.ClientName) || c.ClientName.Contains(filter.ClientName)) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.ClientEmail) || c.ClientEmail.Contains(filter.ClientEmail)) &&
            (!filter.Status.HasValue || c.Status == filter.Status)
            && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.CreatedBy) || c.CreatedBy.Contains(filter.CreatedBy)) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.CreationDate) || c.CreationDate.Contains(filter.CreationDate)) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.ModifiedBy) || c.ModifiedBy.Contains(filter.ModifiedBy)) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.ModificationDate) || c.ModificationDate.Contains(filter.ModificationDate)) &&
            (!filter.SendStatus.HasValue || c.SendStatus == filter.SendStatus) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SendDate) || c.SendDate.Contains(filter.SendDate))
        );

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    private LicenseFilter GetFilter()
    {
        NameValueCollection filter = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);

        return new LicenseFilter
        {
            AppName = filter["AppName"],
            license = filter["license"],
            ClientName = filter["ClientName"],
            ClientEmail = filter["ClientEmail"],
            Status = (filter["Status"] == "0") ? (Status?)null : (Status)int.Parse(filter["Status"]),
            CreatedBy = filter["CreatedBy"],
            CreationDate = filter["Date"],
            ModifiedBy = filter["ModifiedBy"],
            ModificationDate = filter["Date"],
            SendStatus = (filter["SendStatus"] == "0") ? (SendStatus?)null : (SendStatus)int.Parse(filter["SendStatus"]),
            SendDate = filter["Date"]
        };
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]License license)
    {
        try
        {
            //Here, I suppose to just call the dll to generate the license and save it, instead of doing this.
                addr = new MailAddress(User.Identity.Name);
                string username = addr.User;
                license.AppName = LicenseManagerController._appName;
                //license.license = license from module;
                license.CreatedBy = username;
                license.CreationDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
                if (license.SendStatus == SendStatus.Sent)
                {
                    license.SendDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
                }
                DB.Licenses.Add(license);
                DB.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception insert)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(insert.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Any ideas to help me out a little bit?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this 'DLL module' that you speak of?

Comment: A DLL I am making, also: is going to generate the app keys and suppose to save them into an existing Database along with the app´s name and the username that will receive the key

Comment: So, from the MVC app, I am going to add it as a reference, to use its publics methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, I now get the gist of what you are trying to achieve.

Using the DLL, if you want to access a *specific* database connection string then you can access the app configuration (In your case web.config).

1.) Add reference to `System.Configuration` on your DLL project
2.) Use [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the config file of your application (Either windows or web app)

Now, if you want a dynamic connection string then you should expose a public method on your DLL that accepts a connection string. Input can be from user or whatever source you may come up with.

Also, you can add a config file for your DLL but since it's too troublesome to manage why not use the current config file of your application referencing the DLL right right? :)

Comment: So...it should be something like this: public void whatever(string connection){ SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connection); ... etc, right? >>> then from my app I pass the connection as a string

Comment: If you don't want to read from a config file then you can do that. It's more dynamic and is a good design based on the use of your DLL

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> So, since the Database is created in the MVC application, how can I make the dll module to check into that database, to make sure the app does not have that key already, and then, save it into the database as well?

The database is located using a database connection string. This is usually specified in web.config or app.config, depending on the type of applications. All applications with physical access to the database including appropriate security credentials can use that same connection string to access the same database.

DLL modules don't run on their own. They are loaded into an application domain (commonly a web application or windows application). The connection string is generally provided in the web.config or app.config of the program that references and loads the DLL.

Comment: So, you mean, the connection string should be in the dll´s appconfig, instead of the webconfig where I have it now?

Comment: DLLs don't (usually) have app.config files. The application that uses the DLL does.